# rsync corrupted my system partition. Does anyone know why and how to recover?

Tags: backup, rsync, recovery, disaster-recovery

I did an rsync to a partition on a second drive (mounted symbolically linked).  It seemed to go OK, but then terminal was complaining that my system partition was read-only.  I tried rebooting and it no longer boots.  It complains it couldn't mount `/tmp/` then just stops with a black screen and cursor in the top left corner.

When I boot from a USB key there is nothing obviously chewed up.  At a glance my files and folders all seem to be there.  And they seem to be on my backup partition.  Specifically the `/etc/fstab` looks good.

I found one minor error in my syntax on my backup bash, but that doesn't seem to explain this.  I put `-e` SSH (extraneously) it wasn't meant to be over SSH and I didn't include a server.  (I forgot all about `--dry-run`.  I should have done it.)  Here is the command line of interest from bash (below)

Does anyone know what this would corrupt and how to fix it?

#Now do the backup

```
rsync -aAXve ssh --progress --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found","/etc/udev/devices","/OSBack/*","/VPSBack/*","/JingleShare/*","/jstorage/*","/home/*/.cache","/home/*/.thumbnails","/home/*/.local/share/Trash","/home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*/Cache","/etc/fstab","/var/run/*","/var/lock/*","/lib/modules/*/volatile/.mounted","/var/cache/apt/archives/*","/home/joe/Dropbox/*"} /* /$BACKUP_DIR
```

Comment: Does `/tmp` still exist? What are its permissions `stat --printf %A\\n /tmp`?

Comment: Well you know how it offers to attempt to fix errors.  I pressed 'F' to fix errors and viola, it really fixed the thing and then it booted.  So whatever got corrupted was within the 'F' fix errors reach.
I'm pretty sure /tmp was there.  Anyway it's there now and fully working, so I can't get forensic info at this point.
I'm going to retry the rsync without the extraneous -e ssh and see if that works better.  If not then I still have a problem that scync is corrupting the source that it is supposed to be backing up.

Comment: The summary is that I recovered from this issue by using the 'F' fix disk option during boot time.  I'm still curious about what went wrong with rsync, but I'm not dead in the water anymore.

Comment: What I was leaning towards was `/tmp` was some how removed or the permissions were changed, or perhaps the sticky bit was changed on the /tmp directory, but as you have run `fsck` and you are able to boot... maybe you could try breaking it again and see? :D

Comment: So you're saying that the F) Fix disk during boot is just fsck?  If it breaks again on an rsync I'll have a look at the /tmp.  Do you suspect that you could break the boot by messing with the /tmp dir's flags?  Any guess as to how/why rsync could mess up the tmp dir (especially when it wasn't even backing up the /tmp dir)?

Comment: A way to know if that was what the F) option was would be to run `shutdown -rF now` and force into fsck on next boot. As too why rsync would/could do that I have no idea. I was only going based on that it was complaining about `/tmp` on boot and then was hanging.